# Running AntlrWorks2 stand-alone on Windows 7

Tags: windows, antlrworks

I must be missing something. After downloading AntlrWorks2 I found the executable bin/antlrworks2.exe and bin/antlrworks264.exe. Aren't these supposed to be the standalone version of the tool? Neither works for me; after a NetBeans splash screen, the first times around I got an error message on missing packages; after a couple of times I chose to go on regardless, but now (still after the initial spash screen) there is simply nothing happening at all.

I can't find any tutorial or manual detailing how to run AntlrWorks stand-alone, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, running either of those exe-s should launch ANTLRWorks2. Do you perhaps get some pointers when running either exe-s from your command prompt instead of launching them from your Windows Explorer (assuming that is what you've done so far...).

Comment: Indeed there's a log file. Not sure how to include it here, but the first few lines run:  
`Warning - could not install some modules:
 org.netbeans.core.multiview - The module named org.openide.windows was needed and not found.`  
(and so on for 50 or so modules)

Answer (score 7):

This is due to a bug in the NetBeans platform. I filed a report but it hasn't received a reply yet:
[Cannot launch platform application after moving installation folder](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=227219)

Here is a workaround that does not delete any preferences you have customized:

> I found that deleting just the `var` folder under the user's generated
>   `.antlrworks2` settings folder resolves the issue...

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't change anything for me (assuming that's the `dev/var` folder - I don't see any other); the folder just gets recreated next time I run the tool - command line or from the explorer, doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @Arend, and what about removing the entire `.antlrworks2` folder? Needless to say, that will undo any custom setting you made to ANTLRWorks.

Comment: @Bart: no luck there, the problem keeps occurring and the folder just gets created again

Comment: Worked for me. I removed the entire .antlrworks folder in \users\username\AppData\Roaming

Answer (score 3):

Still an issue as of date of this post.  Deleting the `.antlrworks2` folder from \users\username\AppData\Roaming does work - you can find this folder by putting `%APPDATA%` into your file explorer address bar (exactly as shown) - that will go to the app data folder for your current user login session.  Delete the `.antlrworks2` folder and then re-run the app.